# Subtracting dates - difference in hours vs secs?

Tags: r, datediff, lubridate

Sorry I don't have a reproducible example here.

Can anyone explain or have a guess as to why one of these differences comes our in days and the other in seconds?

```
> str(dat)
$ Date.Of.Visit           : chr  "2010-02-11" "2010-05-13" "2012-10-16" "2014-03-24" ...
$ Date.Diagnosed          : chr  "2003-08-23" "2003-08-23" "2003-08-23" NA ...
$ Date.Of.Birth           : chr  "1992-01-19" "1992-01-19" "1992-01-19" NA ...
```

All look the same.

```
dat$Date.Of.Visit <- ymd(dat$Date.Of.Visit)
dat$Date.Diagnosed <- ymd(dat$Date.Diagnosed)
dat$Date.Of.Birth <- ymd(dat$Date.Of.Birth)
```

All put through the same lubridate function.

```
> class(dat$Date.Of.Visit)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> class(dat$Date.Of.Birth)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> class(dat$Date.Diagnosed)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

All look the same.

```
> (dat$Date.Of.Visit - dat$Date.Of.Birth)[1:10]
Time differences in days
 [1] 6598 6689 7576   NA 3043 3141 3218 6784 4813 4974

> (dat$Date.Diagnosed - dat$Date.Of.Birth)[1:10]
Time differences in secs
 [1] 365817600 365817600 365817600        NA 256003200 256003200 256003200 243302400 194486400 194486400
```

The only thing I can think is Date.Of.Visit is complete, Date.Of.Birth and Date.Diagnosed have a few spots of missing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to answer conclusively without your original data, but take a look at the code for `difftime`, which is used to subtract `POSIXct` objects:

```
> difftime
function (time1, time2, tz, units = c("auto", "secs", "mins",
    "hours", "days", "weeks"))
{
    if (missing(tz)) {
        time1 <- as.POSIXct(time1)
        time2 <- as.POSIXct(time2)
    }
    else {
        time1 <- as.POSIXct(time1, tz = tz)
        time2 <- as.POSIXct(time2, tz = tz)
    }
    z <- unclass(time1) - unclass(time2)
    attr(z, "tzone") <- NULL
    units <- match.arg(units)
    if (units == "auto") {
        if (all(is.na(z)))
            units <- "secs"
        else {
            zz <- min(abs(z), na.rm = TRUE)
            if (is.na(zz) || zz < 60)
                units <- "secs"
            else if (zz < 3600)
                units <- "mins"
            else if (zz < 86400)
                units <- "hours"
            else units <- "days"
        }
    }
    switch(units, secs = .difftime(z, units = "secs"), mins = .difftime(z/60,
        units = "mins"), hours = .difftime(z/3600, units = "hours"),
        days = .difftime(z/86400, units = "days"), weeks = .difftime(z/(7 *
            86400), units = "weeks"))
}
```

So, if `any(is.na(z))` or `min(abs(z), na.rm = TRUE) < 60` is satisfied by the subtraction, since you aren't specifying `units`, then the units are forced to seconds.  For example:

```
> difftime("2014-03-24", c(NA,NA,NA))
Time differences in secs
[1] NA NA NA

> difftime("2014-03-24", c('2010-01-01',NA,NA))
Time differences in days
[1] 1542.958       NA       NA

> difftime("2014-03-24", c('2010-01-01','2014-03-24',NA))
Time differences in secs
[1] 133311600         0        NA
```

The most likely culprit is that somewhere the difference between `Date.Diagnosed` and `Date.Of.Birth` is less than a minute -- based on what you've pasted here, neither of those vectors contain only `NA` values, which rules out the `all(is.na(z))` switch.

Comment: And the solution is of course to use `difftime` explicitly (with a specified unit) instead of `-.POSIXt`.